# matching array based on specific elements

Tags: python, arrays, matching

I would really appreciate some help. I am trying to return matches from 2 arrays:

```
array([
[['A', 'B', 'C’],['SOLUTION 1]],
   [['X’, 'Y'],['SOLUTION 2', 'SOLUTION 3']]
], dtype=object)


array([
['ID1100259',['A', 'B', 'C’]],
['ID1101424', ['X’, 'Y']]
], dtype=object)
```

Basically the first array is a recommender system (if records from the second array match those in the first array then the solution needs to be appended to the second array). I’m hoping to obtain a final dataframe with 3 columns

```
/ID1100259/ 'A', 'B', 'C’/SOLUTION 1/ 

/ID1101424/ 'X’, 'Y'/ 'SOLUTION 2', 'SOLUTION 3'/
```

I’m trying with the following code but it just gives me matches of elements

```
new_list = []
for element in array2:
    if element in array1:
        new_list.append(element)
```

Comment: Hi @tezzaaa.  Are you using the `pandas` library?  The use of "dataframe" implies you are, but it's not clear from your code.  Also - could you include the actual code where you set up `array1` and `array2`?  That will help people to give you more useful answers.

Comment: hi, originally i had the data in pandas df but i converted in array as i needed it in that format for recommender system. The code and original data is very long as i did other manipulation